# Spark SQL - data comparison

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, bigdata

What would be the best approach to compare two csv files (millions of rows) with same schema with a primary key column and print out the differences. For example ,

### CSV1

```
Id  name   zip   
1   name1  07112  
2   name2  07234  
3   name3  10290
```

### CSV2

```
Id  name    zip   
1   name1   07112  
2   name21  07234  
4   name4   10290
```

Comparing modified file CSV2 with the original data CSV1,

### Output should be

```
Id name    zip   
2  name21  07234 Modified  
3  name3   10290 Deleted  
4  name4   10290 Added
```

New to Spark SQL, I am thinking of importing data into Hive tables and then run Spark SQL to identify the changes.

1) Is there any row modified method available to identify whether a row has modified instead of comparing values in each column?
2) Are there any better approach available to implement either using Spark or other HDFS tools?

Appreciate the feedback

Comment: Down voting : What have you tried?

Comment: @thebluephantom yes.. it works!  I will also be running some benchmarks against custom C# / python code with a hash code (to identify modified row). hopefully this spark approach would be the better performing. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many approaches exist; this is one that can have things done in parallel:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val origDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("1", "a", "b"),
  ("2", "c", "d"),
  ("3", "e", "f")
)).toDF("k", "v1", "v2")

val newDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("1", "a", "b"),
  ("2", "c2", "d"),
  ("4", "g", "h")
)).toDF("k", "v1", "v2")

val df1 = origDF.except(newDF) // if k not exists in df2, then deleted
//df1.show(false)
val df2 = newDF.except(origDF) // if k not exists in df1, then added
//df2.show(false)

                           // if no occurrence in both dfs, then the same
                           // if k exists in both, then k in df2 = modified

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

val df3 = spark.sql("""SELECT df1.k, df1.v1, df1.v2, "deleted" as operation
                         FROM  df1 
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT df2.k 
                                            FROM df2
                                            WHERE df2.k = df1.k)
                          UNION
                       SELECT df2.k, df2.v1, df2.v2, "added" as operation
                         FROM  df2 
                         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT df1.k 
                                             FROM df1
                                            WHERE df1.k = df2.k)
                          UNION
                       SELECT df2.k, df2.v1, df2.v2, "modified" as operation
                         FROM  df2 
                        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT df1.k 
                                        FROM df1
                                        WHERE df1.k = df2.k)

                   """)

df3.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+---+---+---------+
|k  |v1 |v2 |operation|
+---+---+---+---------+
|4  |g  |h  |added    |
|2  |c2 |d  |modified |
|3  |e  |f  |deleted  |
+---+---+---+---------+
```

Not so hard, no standard utility.